# Klaviyo - Removed download button from image, how can I remove mouse over events?

Tags: django

With this variable {{ emptyURL|add:"#" }} I removed the download button from my image (small download button that appears in bottom right corner when you hover over the image) but when you hover with mouse the pointer becomes hand, how to stop that from happening?

Comment: Can you include some more html from your template please. Where you use this code

Comment: This is a printscreen of a field to enter URLs or some variables https://prnt.sc/y0gys8